# Find text not within HTML tags with Javascript (regex)

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string from a DOM element, which contains something similar to the following:

```
<span class='greenhornet'>Can you catch the green?</span>
```

I need to know the position of the word **green**.

In this case, if I setup a pattern `/green/`, JS `exec()` of course will return the first occurrence of **green** (position 13).

Is there a way to tell JS regexp to ignore `!` the word **green**, if it's between `<` and `>` or is there an easier way to do this?

Oh, and I can't just strip the HTML either!

thanks.

Comment: [Please don't parse HTML with Regex](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html)

Comment: Can you use `document.getElementsByClassName` for example?

Comment: Use DOM to retrieve all text nodes, concatenate the text node contents, _then_ do your search. This would cover cases like matching "green hornet" even when split by HTML, _e.g._ `<b>green</b>` hornet.

Comment: *Why* can't you strip the HTML?

Answer (score 2):

As the commentors (and user1883592) have suggested, stripping the HTML or parsing the text out of the HTML is the correct answer here.  Using regular expressions with HTML is a loser's game; you've been warned.

But, that being said, if you really want to play that game, I'd start by ensuring there are no opening brackets in between your term and the last closing bracket; in other words:

```
var greenRegex = />[^<]+(green)/;
var position = "<span class='greenhornet'>Can you catch the green?</span>".search(greenRegex);
// position = 25, not 13
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get innerHTML of the span element. No Regex needed.